# How to return a value from an if statement and store it in a variable? Jquery

Tags: javascript

this is an extremely simple one but I seem to be struggling.

This is my code -

```
var type = ageSort(currentObject)



    function ageSort(currentObject) {
        
        if (currentObject.year >= 1985) {
            return "Modern";
        } else if (currentObject.year < 1985 && year >= 1970) {
            return "Bronze"; 
        } else if (currentObject.year < 1970 && year >= 1956 ) {
            return "Silver";
        } else if (currentObject.year < 1956) {
            return "Gold";
        }
    }
```

All I want to do is store the return value in the "type" variable, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Your code refers to `year` without the `currentObject` context; is `year` a separate global variable?

Comment: Also there are redundant comparisons. If you get through the first `if` condition, then you know that the year is less than 1985, so no explicit comparison is necessary.

Comment: Also also, you didn't say exactly what the problem is. Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported in the browser console?

Comment: Hi @Pointy, No errors, just doesnt seem to return anything.

Comment: What do you mean "Your code refers to year without the currentObject context" is that not the purpose of globalObject.year?

Comment: Nothing in your question explains the difference between `currentObject.year` and `year`. Where do they come from?

Comment: Apologies, year is:

var year = comics[this].year;

Comment: using breakpoints, the year is being filled in correctly, its hitting the correct if statements, but not returning the value

Comment: JavaScript is not broken. If a `return` statement like the ones in your code is executed, then the value will definitely be returned. The only way your function can return nothing is if none of the `if` conditions succeed. In that case, it will return `undefined`.

Comment: you really need to ```console.log(currentObject)``` and share its output here - else for all we know you are comparing strings with ints!! and you have no default return from your function

Comment: It's my own dumb fault. Been a front end developer for a year and totally forgot to perform .toLowerCase() on the result, it was a capitalisation error. Such a simple mistake and it's been driving me insane because I've been overthinking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define `currentObject` like so:

```
var currentObject = { year: 1995 };
```

And place a `console.log` below the call to show the result:

```
var type = ageSort(currentObject);
console.log(type);
```

Afterwards we need to change the following small issues:

- `year >= 1956` should be `currentObject.year >= 1956` (same for next line)

Applying those fixes, the code prints `Modern` with input year `1995` as you can test here:

```js
var currentObject = { year: 1995 };

var type = ageSort(currentObject)
console.log(type);

function ageSort(currentObject) {
    if (currentObject.year >= 1985) {
        return "Modern";
    } else if (currentObject.year < 1985 && currentObject.year >= 1970) {
        return "Bronze"; 
    } else if (currentObject.year < 1970 && currentObject.year >= 1956 ) {
        return "Silver";
    } else if (currentObject.year < 1956) {
        return "Gold";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the code and @Pointy's comment, I believe you intended the following code:

```js
var type = ageSort(currentObject)



    function ageSort(currentObject) {
        
        if (currentObject.year >= 1985) {
            return "Modern";
        } else if (currentObject.year < 1985 && currentObject.year >= 1970) {
            return "Bronze"; 
        } else if (currentObject.year < 1970 && currentObject.year >= 1956 ) {
            return "Silver";
        } else if (currentObject.year < 1956) {
            return "Gold";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem (if there is any) is in the data (maybe currentObject.year isn't a trusted value).

By the way use `console.log()` to display data -> and to share with stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) the result or display it in HTML.

Also, define `year`.

```js
function ageSort(currentObject) {

  if (currentObject.year >= 1985) {
    return "Modern";
  } else if (currentObject.year < 1985 && currentObject.year >= 1970) {
    return "Bronze";
  } else if (currentObject.year < 1970 && currentObject.year >= 1956) {
    return "Silver";
  } else if (currentObject.year < 1956) {
    return "Gold";
  }
}

var currentObject = {
  year: 1956
}

var type = ageSort(currentObject);

console.log(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceError

```
    } else if (currentObject.year < 1985 && year >= 1970) {
        return "Bronze"; 
    }
```

the secound part of the else if statement is not defined. year should be currentObject.year

https://jsfiddle.net/e9tpfm36/18/